# Magento 2 - SOAP Consumer is not authorized to access

Tags: magento2, api, soap

In my Magento 2.0.13 is working, but on Magento 2.1.5 I received this message below when I accessed **mystore.com/soap/default?wsdl&services=catalogProductRepositoryV1**

> I don't want create a separed script.

```
<env:Code>
    <env:Value>env:Sender</env:Value>
</env:Code>
<env:Reason>
    <env:Text xml:lang="en">Consumer is not authorized to access %resources</env:Text>
</env:Reason>
```

This command is working **mystore.com/soap/default?wsdl_list=1** on my Magento 2.1.5.

I believe that isn't issue related to the version, I used this reference:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/soap/bk-soap.html

Comment: that happens if you don't supply the acces token. Could you include your full code?

Comment: I haven't code, I have a different result to each Magento version directly on the browser.